# Trouble debugging android wear over bluetooth - Unable to connect to localhost

Tags: android, debugging, bluetooth, wear-os, moto-360

I can't debug over bluetooth with my Moto360.

To start I have enabled "ADB debugging" and "Debug over Bluetooth" on the Moto360.  I have also enabled "Debugging over Bluetooth" via the companion phone.  It shows:

> Host: disconnected
>
> Target: connected

When I connect the companion phone via USB, I can see it connect to adb using:

```
./adb devices
```

Then I try:

```
./adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub
```

and then:

```
./adb connect localhost:4444
```

which returns:

> unable to connect to localhost:4444:4444

I've tried a lot of things like resetting the moto360, killing the adb server, rebooting the computer, uninstalling platform tools via sdk manager and reinstalling them, trying a different port number.  Nothing seems to work.

I was able to connect with my personal computer, but every time I try on my work computer I get: unable to connect to localhost:4444:4444

Comment: With reference with google issues tracker it has been fixed. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37091033

Answer (score 142):

I was getting the following error message:

```
unable to connect to localhost:4444: cannot connect to localhost:4444
no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it (10061).
```

I used `adb connect 127.0.0.1:4444` instead and I was prompted with the message instantaneously.

Comment: According to a thread about this on xda, the "Problem stems from systems that resolve IPv6 above IPv4, so localhost becomes ::1: not 127.0.0.1, and ADB clearly doesnt play nice with v6."

Comment: On Windows 10 using Android Studio 1.5 I had to switch to adb connect 127.0.0.1:4444 in order to get the Moto 360 visible

Comment: Also used adb connect 127.0.0.1:4444 and got message instantaneously

Comment: The same problem on OS X El Capitan. This is the correct answer.

Comment: I have this problem from time to time, always forget the solution, and always come back to the same place. I just wanted to say **thank you very much!**

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 17):

Try this instead

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1:4444
```

more:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35093813/2267994

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer

first remove port forwarding;

```
adb forward --remove tcp:4444
```

then do port forwarding steps from the begining

```
adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub
adb connect localhost:4444
```

i fixed my problem with these steps

Answer (score 3):

You can try that, at least, it works for me:

your watch -> developer options -> adb debugging (once disable, then enable).

After that,

adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub

adb connect 127.0.0.1:4444

Answer (score 1):

`Debugging over Bluetooth` was always `Off` for me. Apparently I had to choose a debugging wearable device here:

`Android Wear -> Settings (gear icon) -> Debugging over Bluetooth -> Device to Debug`

Answer (score 1):

- Open the Wear OS app on the Android Phone and Go to `Advanced Settings` (Lowermost option in app after scrolling).
- Check that `Debugging over Bluetooth` switch is OFF. Turn is `ON`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good collection of commands you might need: [commands](http://technofob.com/bluetooth-debugging-on-android-wear/)

I had a different connection problem which where not solved by any suggetions. In the end I found out that adb has a "problem" when 2 mobile devices with bluetooth debugging enabled are connected with the computer - it just connects to the first one, so keep in mind to detach other devices or check by using: adb devices which one was chosen. It is not an issue of adb but of my setup. It did cost some time to figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this.
If you have a emulator preview connected first go inside Android Wear app to the emulator and choose FORGET.

Later use the commands all are using

```
adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub
adb connect localhost:4444
```

That work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

If you have connected the emulator you can see the same problem, just disconnect the emulator or shutdown and later repeat the commands that's all.