# Unable to debug over Bluetooth with android wear - Host Disconnected

Tags: android, debugging, bluetooth, adb, lg

So I'm currently trying to follow this guide [on Debugging over Bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html) but am coming to some problems when attempt to connect to the local host.

I have used the top voted answer [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656967/trouble-debugging-android-wear-over-bluetooth-unable-to-connect-to-localhost) and where I was previously getting an error stating "No connection would be made because the target machine actively refused it", I now receive a message stating "connected to 127.0.0.1:4444".

However, when I go onto the Android wear app on my mobile, it is still showing that the host device is disconnected.

I have also followed the steps [in this article](http://melix.github.io/blog/2014/10/android-moto360.html) but after following the steps and restarting both devices, my phone is unable to connect with my watch again so I have to run a factory reset. I have tried to repeat the steps again after the factory reset but my mobile is still saying the Host is disconnected.

I am using the following:

Smartwatch: LG G Watch

Mobile: Samsung Galaxy Alpha running KitKat

Comment: I am facing same problem, Have you found exact reason why this is happening

Comment: After I did Factory Reset to my It start working - God knows what was problem here is useful article http://melix.github.io/blog/2014/10/android-moto360.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying this with another device (Samsung Galaxy s6) and having no success, I changed the cable that the mobile was being connect to the host machine with. Seems to have fixed the problem!